# Cart/Checkout ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey (PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR on Heroku but not Localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

have a working cart/checkout functionality on my app which works perfectly fine on localhost, but when I deploy to Heroku items don't get added to the cart when the "Add to Cart" button is clicked.

The Heroku logs show this for the error:

```
2017-05-19T21:12:00.506230+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/order_items" for 68.225.227.137 at 2017-05-19 21:12:00 +0000
2017-05-19T21:12:00.508991+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by OrderItemsController#create as JS
2017-05-19T21:12:00.511223+00:00 app[web.1]: User Load (0.8ms) SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1 [["id", 1]]
2017-05-19T21:12:00.509041+00:00 app[web.1]: Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "order_item"=>{"quantity"=>"1", "product_id"=>"2"}, "commit"=>"Add to Cart"}
2017-05-19T21:12:00.516450+00:00 app[web.1]: Product Load (0.7ms) SELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."active" = $1 AND "products"."id" = $2 LIMIT 1 [["active", "t"], ["id", 2]]
2017-05-19T21:12:00.513630+00:00 app[web.1]: (0.6ms) BEGIN
2017-05-19T21:12:00.531537+00:00 app[web.1]: SQL (12.8ms) INSERT INTO "orders" ("user_id", "subtotal", "created_at", "updated_at", "order_status_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id" [["user_id", 1], ["subtotal", "499.0"], ["created_at", "2017-05-19 21:12:00.517193"], ["updated_at", "2017-05-19 21:12:00.517193"], ["order_status_id", 1]]
2017-05-19T21:12:00.532478+00:00 app[web.1]: (0.8ms) ROLLBACK
2017-05-19T21:12:00.533488+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-05-19T21:12:00.532671+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 24ms (ActiveRecord: 15.8ms)
2017-05-19T21:12:00.533491+00:00 app[web.1]: DETAIL: Key (order_status_id)=(1) is not present in table "order_statuses".
2017-05-19T21:12:00.533490+00:00 app[web.1]: ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey (PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR: insert or update on table "orders" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_7a22cf8b0e"
2017-05-19T21:12:00.533492+00:00 app[web.1]: : INSERT INTO "orders" ("user_id", "subtotal", "created_at", "updated_at", "order_status_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"):
2017-05-19T21:12:00.533493+00:00 app[web.1]: app/controllers/order_items_controller.rb:7:in `create'
2017-05-19T21:12:00.533494+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-05-19T21:12:00.533495+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-05-19T21:12:06.465383+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/order_items" host=aloop-offroad.herokuapp.com request_id=b13e7b04-7ac0-44fe-b58f-a850ce4cd7e8 fwd="68.225.227.137" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=16ms status=500 bytes=1754 protocol=http
```

Can anyone see what's happening?  I'm lost because I can't see anything that would work on `localhost` but not `Heroku`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is, boiled down, that you're trying to insert a record into `orders` with a value for `order_status_id` that violates a constraint. This is probably because you seeded your database locally with a few `OrderStatus` objects and hardcoded their ids into your code. Those records don't exist in your production database, though. You should probably update your code to pull the order status options from the database on request, and then create the relevant status records in your production database.

Comment: Ahhhhhh!  Thank you!  That was driving me crazy!